# Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time1, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, string, time, diff, lubridate

I am substringing daily hours/minutes (1:00,2:00,..., 13:30,..., 22:30, 24:10) for an schedule df string colum for initial and final hour,
after that I would like to take the difference in hours between them.

Here's my attempt:

```
# intial string example #

df[1, "schedule"] 

 // console output//
"14:00H ÀS 22:18H - 1H DE DESCANSO"

## setting hour and minutes format ##
initial_hour <- hm(
                    as.character(
                    factor(
                    substr(
                    df$schedule, 
                    start = 1,
                    stop  = 5)
                    )))

final_hour <-   hm(
                    as.character(
                    factor(
                    substr(
                    df$schedule,
                     start = 11,
                     stop =  15))))

# hour difference ##
difftime(final_hour, initial_hour, tz = Sys.timezone(location = TRUE) , units = "hours")

// console output //

Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time1, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Is it possible to set "origin" inside the argument function?

Comment: Could you please add the output from dput(head(df, 5))

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be using `lubridate`, you could just substract the periods without `difftime`:

```
h1 <- lubridate::hm('24:10')
h2 <- lubridate::hm('23:05')

h1-h2

#> [1] "1H 5M 0S"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Putting it into a dataframe and using `dplyr` and `lubridate`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
   mutate(time_difference =
             hm(
                substr(schedule, 
                       start = 11,
                       stop  = 15)
             ) - 
             hm(
                substr(schedule, 
                       start = 1,
                       stop  = 5)
             ))

#> Note: method with signature 'Period#ANY' chosen for function '-',
#>  target signature 'Period#Period'.
#>  "ANY#Period" would also be valid

#>                            schedule time_difference
#> 1 14:00H ÀS 22:18H - 1H DE DESCANSO       8H 18M 0S
#> 2 18:00H ÀS 16:18H - 1H DE DESCANSO      -2H 18M 0S
```

Your entry plus one more for data

```r
df <- data.frame(
   schedule = c("14:00H ÀS 22:18H - 1H DE DESCANSO",
                "18:00H ÀS 16:18H - 1H DE DESCANSO")
)
```